# Xubuntu Requirements

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, xubuntu, system-installation

I plan to install Xubuntu on my CPU that has the following specs:

Intel Pentium(R) 4 2.26 GHz, 1.00 GB of RAM.

Would the Xubuntu Trusty Tahr support my CPU or do I have to use the Precise Pangolin version?

Comment: Afaik CPU compatibility is only an issue if your CPU does not support PAE or SSE. With the exception of some Pentium-M models and some exotic CPUs for embedded applications all processors since the Pentium 3 support both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely go with Trusty. My CPU is a lot older, and it runs it pretty well.

Be aware however that to my knowledge there are still unfixed bugs with Trusty in relation to power management on laptops.